# response.redirect() is not working in express (NodeJS)

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I want redirect to dashboard.html from login.html if username is correct, if not then alert box will be shown, I used both express response.redirect('path') or response.sendFile('path') but none is working here. 
I am using angularJs as front-end and express module of nodeJs in back-end.

Express route code:

```
    module.exports = function(app,db,path){
        app.post('/student-login', function (request, response) {
        var user = request.body;
        if(user.username == "abhinav")
        {   
            response.redirect('/views/dashboard.html');
            response.end();
        }
        else{
            response.send("Wrong username");
            response.end();
        }
   });
}
```

AngularJs code:

```
angular.module('loginService',[])
.service('loginService',function($http){
        return {
            sendStudent : function(data){
            return $http.post('/student-login',data)
            .then(function(response){
                    return response.data;
                });
              }         
            }
});
```

AngularJs controller Code:

```
if ($scope.myForm.$valid)
            loginService.sendStudent($scope.studentData)
            .then(function(data){
                if(data=="Wrong username")
                alert(data);
            });
```

Developer option > Network : 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the *Network* tab, browser does make a request to the `/views/dashboard.html` route. It means that redirect is working. The reason why you don't get the expected behavior is because you need to **navigate** to that page (right now you are simply loading content of the page).

I would suggest moving redirection logic from express to frontend and using http status codes to signal login errors.

Express code:

```
module.exports = function(app,db,path){
    app.post('/student-login', function (request, response) {
    var user = request.body;
    if (user.username == "abhinav") {   
        response.sendStatus(200);
    } else {
        response.sendStatus(401);
    }
});
}
```

AngularJS controller code:

```
if ($scope.myForm.$valid) {
   loginService.sendStudent($scope.studentData).then(() => {
       // login successful, response status is 200
       location.href = '/views/dashboard.html'
   }).catch(response => {
       if (response.status === 401) {
           alert("Wrong username")
       } else { 
           alert("Some other error") 
       }
   })
}
```

I'm using `location.href` as an example only because I'm not familiar with angularjs routing. It will reload the whole page, use API provided by angularjs router if you want to avoid that.